# Select elements by index in elements name

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Good morning. I have a form that is divided into numbered sections. Sometimes I need to disable some of these sections by using their section numbers. Right now when the function receives an array of section numbers I run a loop to collect them one-by-one. Is there a better, more efficient way of collecting numbered sections by their section numbers with jQuery?

HTML:

```
<div id="frameContent">
<div id="section1">
    <select>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">empty (default)</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">foo</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    <select>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">empty (default)</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">foo</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section3"><select>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">empty (default)</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">foo</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">bar</option>
</select></div>
<div id="section4">
    <select>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">empty (default)</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">foo</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var toggleFormSections = function(frameContent, sectionNumbers, enable) {

    // init empty selector
    var sections = $();

    // collect sections
    for(var i = 0; i < sectionNumbers.length; i++) {
        var section = frameContent.find('div#section' + sectionNumbers[i]);
        sections = sections.add(section);
    }

    // disable/enable sections and elements within
    if(sections.length > 0) {
        if(enable) {
            sections.find('select').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            sections.find('select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
}

// usage:
var frameContent = $('#frameContent');
toggleFormSections(frameContent, [2,3], false);
```

Link to [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XZ9fT/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ9fT/3/

You can easily use jQuery's `each` to loop through the index elements, no need to check it's length. I'm not quite sure, why you want the `enabled` flag. Since you can call it with an empty array to enable everything. This would make it even shorter.

```
$.each(sectionNumbers, function(i) {
  if(enable) {
    frameContent.find('div#section' + sectionNumbers[i] + ' select').prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    frameContent.find('div#section' + sectionNumbers[i] + ' select').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is almost perfect :) What if sectionNumbers is a single number instead of an array? I am using the enable flag to enable some(not all), previously disabled sections or sections that were disabled by default.

Comment: This only works with an array of numbers (or an empty array). You could add a check to the variable to see if it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

One way will be

```
var toggleFormSections = function(frameContent, sectionNumbers, enable) {
    // init empty selector
    var sections = [];

    // collect sections
    for(var i = 0; i < sectionNumbers.length; i++) {
        sections.push('#section' + sectionNumbers[i]);
    }
    sections = $(sections.join(', '))

    sections.find('select').prop('disabled', !enable);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qfAML/)